# SSRS Report PDF Export shows blank pages in higher environment

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have generated a SSRS Report, and then I export the report to PDF. In my Dev environment the PDF has no blank pages. In my QA environment it has alot of blank pages. I have verified that the RDL file is the same on both env.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your content is too wide, although it doesn't seem like that. Check your PageSize and Margins settings for start.
Also, try to make your main content less wide, (same goes for header/footer data), and see what happens.
I had that problem many times and it is very annoying.

Comment: So this is the case, even though the rdl on both environments are the same?

Comment: Other option is that you have some rows that are taking space but have no data (borders, background etc...) and they appear in one of your environments (if data is not the same). To be sure, you can just put border around your data and see how far/wide it shows.